# SQL Server Reporting Services : use Windows authentication

Tags: sql, authentication, reporting-services

I am developing an application in ASP.NET Core and I use SSRS to generate a `.pdf` file for my users to use on my intranet. The problem is that it asks for Windows authentication and I would like it to not ask this if the user is already logged on the computer.

Currently in the `reportserver.config` file on my windows server is this

```
<Authentication>
        <AuthenticationTypes>
            <RSWindowsNTLM/>
        </AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
        <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Proxy</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
        <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
    </Authentication>
```

What do I have to change so my users can just download the `.pdf` file without having to be prompted for username and password all the time?